# Attach Existing browser session in SeleniumLibrary RobotFramework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, robotframework

I have an LDAP alert box that pops up as soon as the browser is opened.

I am Using Robotframework with the seleniumlibrary for my automation scripts.The issue is that the execution of the script hangs after "Open Browser" and none of the succeeding keywords can be executed as a result.

As a work around i created a python keyword to open the browser through:

```
@keyword
def open_browser_and_switch_to_alert(self):
    from selenium import webdriver
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.switch_to_alert()
```

this works just fine, but now i cannot use any of the other SeleniumLibrary keywords of robot framework to access the same browser since it was created seperately.

I need to know if it is possible to be able to use this browser along with the SeleniumLibrary keywords in robotframework?